# Custom theme css separate from editor css

Tags: theming, uri

I have a custom css file in my custom theme folder which has a few changes I made throughout site but does not affect the tinymce editor but probably overrides it making so no changes in text.

I have two problems, one I don't actually know what to put in separate custom css to make buttons work in tinymce editor. I am used to finding a specific div or creating one and then adding the css. I am not familiar with setting up classes for this editor (as it offers in wysiwyg profiles) and correct syntax to do so. Also I would have thought I needed to bring over a generic copy of the css for the editor into my custom theme folder (?) And two I am unclear on how to set the path in define css for the editor profile, if ever I manage to create of find the correct file.

I hope I am making some sense and my question is clear enough.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you question is. Is your CSS file not loading at all in TinyMCE? Or are you having troubles with getting it to show certain styles? Have you defined it at `admin/config/content/wysiwyg`?

Comment: Bold and Italic is not working at all.I don't have a css file to correspond with the editor, that is the first part of my question- do I copy it over from somewhere in wysiwyg module folder to my theme folder? Then how do I set the path correctly to it in 'define css'? They offer different options for path setting like %b which I find confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me add that the answer that I am about to give is the way I would handle it. This could be done in many ways.

Create a separate stylesheet for your text styling (we usually call it `style-type.css`) and place it somewhere appropriate in your theme (for example `/sites/all/themes/your_theme/css/style-type.css`), also use this file for your front-end. Only add styling in this stylesheet for **textual styling**, so for `h1`, `h2`, `strong`, `em`, etc...

Then use the `admin/config/content/wysiwyg` admin page to define the CSS in the appropriate format. We mostly don't use the replacement patterns (like %b) and simply fill in the path relative to your Drupal install (of course, the patterns could be applicable in your case): `/sites/all/themes/your_theme/css/style-type.css`. Make sure `Define CSS` is the active option above the path.

If you need extra styling for stuff like highlighted text, simply make sure you have that styling in your `style-type.css`. For example `.highlighted { color: yellow; }`. And then define it in the `CSS Class` textarea as follows:

```
Highlighted=highlighted
```

Then also make sure you've got the plugin `Styles` enabled. This will give you a dropdown list on the WYSIWYG editor which allows you to add styling that you defined to texts.

Comment: I will give this a go and report back. It has GOT to work! Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask do I just add the list of styles as a declaration of what will be included? Because there is no section I am styling as such...

Comment: Do you mean the textarea `CSS Classes`? You can leave it empty if not applicable. If you do leave it empty and do not want to show any styling classes in the WYSIWYG editor styles dropdown menu, you should disable the plugin `Styles`, since otherwise it will search for all the classes and show them all since you did not define any classes.

Comment: I just want bold and italic to work, they are only ones not working.

Comment: Are you resetting the `strong` and `em` styling with your CSS? If not, and still not working, you could define them yourself in the defined stylesheet, like: `strong { font-weight: bold; }` Still, you should actually try to inspect your element to find out what is resetting your styling.

Comment: hmm this is a mystery to me. Underline and strikethrough and others work fine and that is with no define css. Still I think it is good practice to create an editor css file and define it so I am going with your answer and then if still doesn't work I will inspect in firefox. Thanks :)

Comment: As follow up, in firebug it is inheriting from html.js and that does not include bold and italic but yet to find file to edit.